# Error Manually Creating Table in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

**So just a little background:**

What I'm doing is creating an internal app that allows users to upload CSV files and then stores each file in a new table that certain queries will be run against to do data calculations.  So, I'm building a system where tables are created dynamically as files are uploaded and then can be referenced with a key for the next 60 days to avoid having to re-upload files.  Rather than create dynamic models, which I did look into, I figured the easiest way would be to create a class that just executed the exact SQL I needed for the specific queries and returned the information.

**The Problem:**

My issue at the moment is that I can't get the create_table syntax to work correctly and it keeps throwing an error.  I think I'm just having an issue understanding how it's setting the parameters correctly.  I'm also connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.  So here's my exception page:

[image: Django Error Message]

And here's the couple snippets of script:

table.py:

```
from django.db import connection
import sys

def create_table(table_name):
    print("Table name is: "+str(table_name))
    t_name = table_name
    if not table_exists(table_name):
        with connection.cursor() as c:
            c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (RecordID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), Email varchar(255), Mailbox varchar(255), Domain varchar(255), Match_Type varchar(50), Correction varchar(255))",[t_name])
            return True
    else:
        print("Table Already Exists: "+table_name)
        return False
```

processor.py:

```
from DataStorage.models import RecordList, RecordData
from DataStorage.table import table_exists, create_table
import string, random

def handle_uploaded_file(f,cust_name=None,):
    #Check if our file exists already and is complete
    if RecordList.objects.filter(file_name=f.name).exists():
        item = RecordList.objects.get(file_name=f.name)
        if table_exists(item.table_name):
            return None
        else:
            create_table(item.table_name)
    else:
        with open('files/'+f.name, 'wb') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk);

        guid = generate_guid(12)
        record = RecordList(record_ID=guid,customer_name=cust_name,file_name=f.name,table_name=get_tablename(f.name))
        record.save()
        create_table(record.table_name)
        return guid
```

I've looked all over Stack Overflow and read the documentation here: [Django Executing Custom SQL Directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), but couldn't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name in `CREATE TABLE` should not be quoted. This also means it can't be passed as a parameter (in a prepared statement in your case).

You'll need to use regular string interpolation for it:

```
  c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (<snip>)" % t_name)
```

**You'll have to be very careful not to introduce a SQL injection here**. `t_name` must be properly sanitized (and **that doesn't mean quoted**).

Comment: What about this section from the documentation I linked at the bottom:  

`codecursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '30%%' AND id = %s", [self.id])`

It looks from here like you can specify the parameter within the string, which is what I was trying to do since Django is supposed to take care of SQL Parameterization for you

Comment: @WakeskaterX This query format uses prepared statements which, like I indicated, don't work for `CREATE TABLE`. Now, what you're trying to do is quite unsafe, and at the same time you seem to don't really understand what you're doing. I suggest you pause for some time and figure out what prepared statements and SQL escaping mean before proceeding.

Comment: This is for an internal application, not a public facing site, so I'm just trying to use some basic checks.

I wasn't aware that you couldn't use Parameterization for Create Tables, it's not something I've tried in the past, and it makes sense.  But that does seem to be what I was trying to do wrong.

Comment: @WakeskaterX convert the table name to unicode and use `isalnum()`, and then check that all the charactersare in the ASCII range. That should do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's how the table name is generated when it's submitted, but I also just added the same function in as a check right before it's submitted as a query.  

It is indeed working correctly and generating the table.

Comment: @WakeskaterX Probably better to keep the check close  in case the table name generation gets refactored and changed ;). Glad it's working for you!